# The necessary conditions in a proof by pumping lemma for CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar

Do we need to cover all the cases or just one of them?

For instance, for $L = a^ib^jc^id^j$, the proof is uvw can't contain both a and $c$ and $b$ and $d$, but we don't cover all the cases, for instance uvw can contain as and bs, bs and cs, cs and ds. Don't we have to prove that it never ever works? No matter what string we pick?

Answer (score 0):

The pumping lemma states that

> If $\mathcal{L}$ is context-free, then for *all* strings $\omega$ longer than some $N$ there is at least *one* way to split it into $\omega = \omega_1\omega_a\omega_2\omega_b\omega_3$ ($\omega_a$ or $\omega_b$ non-empty, $\omega_a\omega_2\omega_b$ has length $\leq N$) such that for *all* $n$ also $\omega_1\omega_a^n\omega_2\omega_b^n\omega_3 \in \mathcal{L}$

To find a counter-example, you thus have to show that

> For *every* $N$ there is a string $\omega$ with length at least $N$ such that for *every* partitioning $\omega = \omega_1\omega_a\omega_2\omega_b\omega_3$ ($\omega_a$ or $\omega_b$ non-empty, $\omega_a\omega_2\omega_b$ has length $\leq N$) there is *some* $n$ with  $\omega_1\omega_a^n\omega_2\omega_b^n\omega_3 \notin \mathcal{L}$

Imagine this as the following game, where you want the pumping lemma to fail, and I want it to hold.

1. I give you a length $N$
2. You give me a string $\omega$ larger than $N$
3. I pick a partitioning $\omega = \omega_1\omega_a\omega_2\omega_b\omega_3$
4. You pick an $n$. If $\omega_1\omega_a^n\omega_2\omega_b^n\omega_3 \notin \mathcal{L}$, you win, otherwise I win.

If you can show that there's a strategy for *your* choices in this game with which you *always* win, no matter what choices I take, then you have refuted that pumping lemma and proved the language to be not context-free.